# How can I move the search bar to the top?

Tags: html, css

I am still learning CSS therefore the code may not exactly be perfect. I wanted to ask, how can I move the search bar to the top right corner? It displays below the main text and that does not look good. Any idea?

```css
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.info {
    font-family: "Comfortaa";
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 4.06em;
    
}

.logo {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 1.25em;
}

.search-box {
    float: right;
}

.vyhladavac {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header role="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/cloud.jpg" class="logo" height="50px" width="45px" alt="">
        <p class="info">Spojená škola, Komárňanská 28, Nové Zámky s o. z. Stredná <br> priemyselná škola                           elektrotechnická S. A. Jedlika - Jedlik <br> Ányos Elektrotechnikai                                       Szakközépiskola a Obchodná <br> akadémia - Kereskedelmi akadémia
        </p>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input class="vyhladavac" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: Consider using `<input type="search" />` instead of `<input type="text" />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put two containers side by side, you can use `display:flex` on the parent container.

Therefore, I put the rest of your header into a div called `headLeft`, and the search div is the other container - allowing us to put `display:flex` on the parent container (which in your case is the `.container` div)

Flexbox is a very easy way to arrange containers side-by-side ("inline"), and it is also very useful for centering content both vertically and horizontally.

```css
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:flex; /*  <====  ADDED  */
    border:1px solid red;
}
.headLeft{ /*  <====  ADDED  */ }

.info {
    font-family: "Comfortaa";
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 4.06em;
    
}

.logo {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 1.25em;
}

.search-box {
    float: right;
}

.vyhladavac {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header role="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="headLeft">
        <img src="img/cloud.jpg" class="logo" height="50px" width="45px" alt="">
        <p class="info">Spojená škola, Komárňanská 28, Nové Zámky s o. z. Stredná <br> priemyselná škola                           elektrotechnická S. A. Jedlika - Jedlik <br> Ányos Elektrotechnikai                                       Szakközépiskola a Obchodná <br> akadémia - Kereskedelmi akadémia
        </p>
      </div>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input class="vyhladavac" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</header>
```

#### REFERENCE:

[Must Watch 25min Flexbox tutorial - fast paced](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Best Flexbox cheat sheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.container{ 
position:relative;}
.search-box{
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the search box out of the layout by utilizing the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) attribute. Setting its value to `absolute` will position the element absolutely in the window. Where the element is positioned can then be controlled using the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, or `right` attributes.

You may also need to move other elements on the page as elements with the `absolute` attribute are rendered on their own layer (that may be above existing elements).

```css
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.info {
    font-family: "Comfortaa";
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-left: 4.06em;
    
}

.logo {
   float: left;
   margin-top: 1.25em;
}

.search-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.vyhladavac {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header role="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img/cloud.jpg" class="logo" height="50px" width="45px" alt="">
        <p class="info">Spojená škola, Komárňanská 28, Nové Zámky s o. z. Stredná <br> priemyselná škola                           elektrotechnická S. A. Jedlika - Jedlik <br> Ányos Elektrotechnikai                                       Szakközépiskola a Obchodná <br> akadémia - Kereskedelmi akadémia
        </p>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input class="vyhladavac" type="text" name="" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're wanting. But give this a try. When I tested the code, It shifted the search bar to the top right of the page.

```css
.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```